# How to save PDF from HTML in Azure Functions

Tags: selenium, pdf, web-crawler, azure-functions

I'm developing an application which will have a web crawler for some sites.

The application will trigger a Azure Function by URL where the crawler will start the work.

So far, so good, but, we'll have to save some evidence that the crawler passed though the site. We're thinking of save a PDF file with the screen that the crawler passed, but, as Azure Functions doesn't have GDI+, it won't work with Selenium or PhantomJS.

One different approach can be download the HTML content and somehow save this HTML string (with all the JS and CSS dependency) into a PDF file.

i'd like of some library which can work with Azure Functions to make the screenshot of some URL (or HTML string) and save to PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the App Service Sandbox whose rules Azure Functions live by is going to block most GDI+ API calls. We have had success with one third party library (ByteScout) for some PDF generation needs but I think in your case that type of operation is explicitly blocked.  You can find out more details here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions

There is no workaround that I'm aware of because at the end of the day most of these solutions are relying on GDI+ in the underlying OS (directly or indirectly).

Your only real option is to offload that workload to virtual machine without the restriction on the API.That could take the form of a dedicated VM or something like an Azure Container Instance whose life-cycle you can manage more dynamically as needed.   We do something similar today where we have a message queue being monitored on a VM and our azure function drops the request into the queue for processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh, that's sad to hear, as far as my boss concern, VM is not an option. Maybe we can download all the files that make the site in Azure Functions, save it in a blob and using a Webjob save pdf with PhatomJS or Selenium. What do you think of it ?

Comment: Webjobs are part of the same platform (Azure App Service) so unfortunately you'll have the restriction as well. It's anything that runs in Azure App Service (Functions, Webjobs, etc).   We're strongly exploring ACS for scenarios where we hit blockers in Functions (time limits, GDI+, etc). It's almost instantaneous compute on demand and you only pay for what you use and w/o app service restrictions. There are more considerations of course but it's a lot better then a traditional VM IMO.

Comment: @JoshCarlisle, is this approach you mentioned above still accurate?